# Конвертируем метод в kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пытаюсь преобразовать данный метод в котлин

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
```

Получается что то подобное:

```
val i: Intent = Intent(context!!, RootActivity::class.java)
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    startActivity(i)
```

Но выдаёт ошибку: Type mismatch Requered Context!, Found: Intent
и вроде бы логично что Intent, я ведь явно указал что мне нужен именно он, почему он ссылается на context не очень смекаю. Подскажите как можно корректно конвертировать.

Comment: А на какую строку ругается то? Как `context!!` получаете?

Comment: @rjhdby на последниюю ` startActivity(i);` конкретно на его параметр i

Comment: Так то все вроде ок, код правильный. Возможно вокруг него какой-то треш и угар, приводящий к подобному, творится. Нигде не переопределяли метод startActivity? Как вариант - "провалитесь" в него и посмотрите сигнатуру.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
val intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, SettingsPomodoroActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

а еще, у вас почему-то отличается название классов в двух примерах, возможно не так активити выбрана.